# JSON error when following IBM tutorial on Hyperledger Fabric on Visual Studio Code

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain

I am trying to deploy demo tutorial on IBM Hyperledger plugin for Visual Studio Code. I had no problems some weeks ago but when trying to do it again I am facing getting the error pasted below (error arises when I try to Instantiate the Smart Contract). I have made no changes in the code in the tutorial and I have also tried with my own Java smart contract.

I have also tried to update the Fabric version to 1.4.3, same error.

```
[11/26/2019 11:19:24 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|Gradle build
[11/26/2019 11:19:27 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[11/26/2019 11:19:42 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|:compileJava
[11/26/2019 11:19:42 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java/fabric-chaincode-shim/1.4.2/fabric-chaincode-shim-1.4.2.pom
[11/26/2019 11:19:42 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java/fabric-chaincode-protos/1.4.2/fabric-chaincode-protos-1.4.2.pom
[11/26/2019 11:19:42 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml
[11/26/2019 11:19:44 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/netty/netty-codec-http2/maven-metadata.xml
[11/26/2019 11:19:45 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java/fabric-chaincode-shim/1.4.2/fabric-chaincode-shim-1.4.2.jar
[11/26/2019 11:19:45 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-java/fabric-chaincode-protos/1.4.2/fabric-chaincode-protos-1.4.2.jar
[11/26/2019 11:19:49 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|:processResources NO-SOURCE
[11/26/2019 11:19:49 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|:classes
[11/26/2019 11:19:49 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|:jar
[11/26/2019 11:19:49 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|:assemble
[11/26/2019 11:19:49 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|:check
[11/26/2019 11:19:49 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|:build
[11/26/2019 11:19:55 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|:shadowJar
[11/26/2019 11:19:55 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|
[11/26/2019 11:19:55 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 30s
[11/26/2019 11:19:55 AM] [INFO] cool_lumiere|3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
[11/26/2019 11:20:01 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:01:963 INFO    java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log                                      Updated all handlers the format
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:083 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.routing.impl.RoutingRegistryImpl findAndSetContr Searching chaincode class in urls: [file:/root/chaincode-java/chaincode/chaincode.jar, file:/root/chaincode-java/chaincode/chaincode.jar]
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:155 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.routing.impl.RoutingRegistryImpl findAndSetContr Found class: org.example.MyAssetContract
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:187 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.routing.impl.ContractDefinitionImpl <init>       Found class: org.example.MyAssetContract
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:202 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.routing.impl.RoutingRegistryImpl findAndSetContr Found class: org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.systemcontract.SystemContract
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:206 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.routing.impl.ContractDefinitionImpl <init>       Found class: org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.systemcontract.SystemContract
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:212 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.routing.impl.RoutingRegistryImpl findAndSetContr Looking for the data types
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:222 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.routing.impl.RoutingRegistryImpl findAndSetContr found 1
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:238 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder$MetadataMap putIfNotNul email MyAsset@example.com
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:240 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder$MetadataMap putIfNotNul name MyAsset
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:244 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder$MetadataMap putIfNotNul url http://MyAsset.me
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:251 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder$MetadataMap putIfNotNul url 
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:255 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder$MetadataMap putIfNotNul email 
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:257 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder$MetadataMap putIfNotNul name 
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:259 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder$MetadataMap putIfNotNul url 
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:263 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder$MetadataMap putIfNotNul url 
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:267 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder$MetadataMap putIfNotNul email MyAsset@example.com
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:271 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder$MetadataMap putIfNotNul name MyAsset
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:275 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder$MetadataMap putIfNotNul url http://MyAsset.me
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:278 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder$MetadataMap putIfNotNul url 
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:306 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder initialize              Validating scehma created
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|10:20:04:308 INFO    org.hyperledger.fabric.contract.metadata.MetadataBuilder validate                Running schema test validation
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|Exception in thread "main" org.everit.json.schema.SchemaException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.JsonPointerEvaluator.executeWith(JsonPointerEvaluator.java:91)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.JsonPointerEvaluator.lambda$forURL$1(JsonPointerEvaluator.java:121)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.JsonPointerEvaluator.query(JsonPointerEvaluator.java:151)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.ReferenceLookup.lookup(ReferenceLookup.java:173)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.ReferenceSchemaExtractor.extract(SchemaExtractor.java:193)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.AbstractSchemaExtractor.extract(SchemaExtractor.java:113)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.runSchemaExtractors(SchemaLoader.java:383)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.loadSchemaObject(SchemaLoader.java:360)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.JsonValue$Multiplexer.requireAny(JsonValue.java:46)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.load(SchemaLoader.java:434)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.loadChild(SchemaLoader.java:438)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.ObjectSchemaLoader.addPropertySchemaDefinition(ObjectSchemaLoader.java:70)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.ObjectSchemaLoader.lambda$populatePropertySchemas$9(ObjectSchemaLoader.java:64)
[11/26/2019 11:20:04 AM] [INFO] fabricvscodelocalfabric-peer0.org1.example.com-demoContract-0.0.1|  at org.everit.json.schema.loader.JsonObject.iterateOnEntry(JsonObject.java:84)
[11/26/20
```

Answer (score 1):

VSC plugin uses Fabric Shim 1.4.2, which has a problem with JSON handling as explained in https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/blockchain-vscode-extension/issues/1658

Just updating build.gradle to use 1.4.4 fixes it.